# Is it possible to convert web url to app via Expo

Tags: expo

Is it possible to create an app from a website (url) similar to the [GoNative](https://gonative.io/) service via Expo?

Comment: No. GoNative wraps standard HTML from a website. Expo uses React Native, which is not at all like HTML. If the site was built using React, and always used flexbox for layout, the port would not be that hard, but it would still have to be made manually.

Comment: Ahh. Do you mind putting that as an answer so I can give you credit.